# best way to upload a binary file using FTP

Tags: c#, file, ftp, binary

I have an image file. I upload this to my server using ftp.  Is this the most efficient way to do it?

```
System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftpClient =   (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create( _serverPath + "/" + _filename);
ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ftp://website.ftp",  "thepassword");
ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
rs.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
rs.Close();
FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
uploadResponse.Close();
```

thanks anyone?

Comment: Yes, for example do not read all file in memory (unless you're sure it's small enough). Usually (but you should check by yourself) smaller chunks are a good compromise (especially because you may handle errors for a single chunk).

Comment: thanks for hiding my ftp credentails.  What an idiot i am!

Comment: OK, so around a buffer of 20K do you recommend?

Comment: Let's try best buffer size for you server. The "problem" is that it's not fixed and it changes according to client and connection quality. For example a very big chunk may need to be resent in case of errors in the packet (even if 99% were good). Usually I do it with a small 4K/8K buffer.

Comment: OK -points taken on board. Thank you

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hi, thanks for that link. But, I  posted this question several years ago and that link was posted days ago. So perhaps that question should be flagged as duplicate?

Comment: @Andrew That's not possible as this question does not have an answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Not a problem then :)